# How to update wine

Tags: 18.04, updates, lubuntu, wine

I recently moved from windows to lubuntu 18.04 and i've installed wine 3.14 following this guide (https://linuxconfig.org/install-wine-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux).
How can i update wine to 3.15 without losing all the data of the application that i'm using (for example games saves)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Wine data is stored within the `WINEPREFIX` directory, usually at `/home/$USER/.wine/` unless otherwise defined.  Such directories are not deleted during the upgrade process.  (You'd have to physically delete the directory yourself)

You don't need to worry about that data being 'lost' when you update Wine versions.

However, if you *really* are concerned about that, make a copy of your Wine prefix elsewhere called "wine_backup" or similar with `cp -r ~/.wine ~/.winebackup` first - this way you can always restore the data if the `.wine` directory goes away by doing `rm -rf ~/.wine && cp -r ~/.winebackup ~/.wine` (which will remove a 'bad' wineprefix if it exists and restore the backup.

You may wish to read up on the [WineHQ guide for Ubuntu](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) on how to deploy newer Wine (latest stable) on your system.  They maintain a repository now for Ubuntu versions of the latest Wine.  (I'm on my phone, I can't copy in the data from that site now, but I will at my earliest convenience after work this evening - assuming I remember)

Answer (score 2):

Usually data/programs installed via `wine` are kept in your home directory (under `~/.wine`), so they won't be affected by an upgrade.

As a matter of fact I've upgraded `wine` on my systems for years without any (apparent) problem, both using *official* ubuntu packages and `winehq` provided repos.

As for how to upgrade `wine`, you'll find plenty of examples/tutorials on the net, many on this site, too.